# Changing Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read from another source

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'd like to extend/replace the Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read from a web server as opposed to properties files.

A bit of background:

I work on a project, and we're finding the number of properties files located on the users systems is getting a little unwieldy. We'd like to replace these files with a 'config server' which will store basic key/value pairs and serve them when the user starts up the app.

To avoid making too many changes, I'd like to change the way the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer finds properties - rather than implementing an entirely new way to manage properties. So on startup - Spring will read all properties from a url, and feed these into my spring config xml in the same way as it would have with actual files.

**Bonus!**

If anyone has any ideas how to do this where properties are reloaded from the server **only when they change**, will get bonus points (I have no idea if I have the ability to assign bonus points, but I'll try!). That would be a 'nice to have, if there's not too much effort involved' solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (PPC) already uses the [`Resource` interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) to specfiy the location from where to read properties (via the [`setLocation(Resource)` method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html#setLocation%28org.springframework.core.io.Resource%29) inherited from PropertiesLoaderSupport.

There is an implementing class of this interface called [`URLResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) which probably does what you want. You could simply create a PPC and set the `location` property with a bean of this type to load the properties from a URL instead of a file. This class also supports `file://` type URLs, so you could switch between on- and offline properties loading depending on the URL you use.

Comment: That could work - but will that GET from the url and expect a properties file in return? We can do that, but I was hoping to handle collecting the properties from the server myself.

Comment: It will open an `InputStream` using the given location, so it does not matter if the URL points to a properties file on a remote server or to a dynamic web action which generates the properties on the fly. You could have a remote properties action which allows calling http://example.org/getProps.do?user=pete to render specific properties.

Comment: Thanks Axel, that suits me fine.